# Django: Combining two queries into one

Tags: python, django

I currently struggle to combine `query_1` and `query_2` into one `query_combined`. Do you have an idea how to achieve that?

```
query_1 = (
    Response.objects.filter(
        survey__event=12,
        survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
        answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN,
    ).filter(answers__answer="Very disappointed")
)

query_2 = (
    Response.objects.filter(
        survey__event=12,
        survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
        answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS,
    )
    .annotate(answer_num=Cast("answers__answer", IntegerField()))
    .filter(answer_num__gt=8)
)
```

Here is the solution:

```
combined_query = (
    Response.objects.filter(
        survey__event=12,
        survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
        answers__question__focus__in=[
           QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN,
           QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS,
        ],
    )
    .annotate(
        answer_NPS=Case(
            When(
                answers__question__type=QuestionType.NPS,
                then=Cast(
                    'answers__answer', output_field=IntegerField()
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .filter(
        answers__choices__answer="Very disappointed",
        answer_NPS__gte=9
    ).order_by("-created")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 from django.db.models import Q

 Response.objects.filter(
        survey__event=12,
        survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
        answers__answer="Very disappointed",
     answer_num__gt=8,Q(answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN) 
   | Q(answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS)
    ).annotate(answer_num=Cast("answers__answer", IntegerField()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably using [`django.db.models.Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) could help. Something in the lines of the following (haven't tested it so might require some tweaking):

```
combined_query = (
    Response.objects.filter(
        survey__event=12,
        survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
        answers__question__focus__in=[
           QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN,
           QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS,
        ],
    )
    .annotate(answer_num=Cast("answers__answer", IntegerField()))
    .filter(Q(answers__answer="Very disappointed") | Q(answer_num__gt=8))
)
```

Comment: If I want "Very disappointed" and gt=8 to be true, I use the `&` operator instead of `|`, correct?

Comment: The problem with that solution is currently that all answers are transformed to an IntegerField. However, it is only QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS that can be Integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `|` operator of the `Q` object to combine the two queries:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query_combined = (
    Response.objects.filter(
        survey__event=12,
        survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT
    )
    .annotate(answer_num=Cast("answers__answer", IntegerField()))
    .filter(
        Q(
            answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN,
            answers__answer="Very disappointed"
        ) |
        Q(
            answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS,
            answer_num__gt=8
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Ah interesting. If I want BOTH conditions to be true not "or" I use `&` instead of `|` ?

Comment: Yes, but then you would want to use `answers__question__focus__in=(QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN, QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS)` since `answers__question__focus` can't be both values at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean moving it up as @davecaputo did? I just tried to add the & but the QuerySet is empty after that change

Comment: I think the problem is that currently with that solution, all answers are transformed into integer fields. However, it should only be for the answers of `QuestionFocus .RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible using [Q expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Is it worth making the code more complex to save one query? Anyway, here's a shot at it, untested...

```
Response.objects.filter(
    survey__event=12,
    survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT
).annotate(answer_num=Cast("answers__answer", IntegerField())
).filter(
     ( Q(answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN) & 
       Q(answers__answer="Very disappointed") ) 
     |
       Q(answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS) &
       Q(answer_num__gt=8)
)
```

It's not *exactly* the same, because all objects retrieved by the first half will also now be annotated.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to avoid that all answers are transformed to an IntegerField? It should only be for `QuestionFocus .RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS`.

Comment: Add a second annotation without the Cast, and choose between them while processing the returned objects?

Comment: I just updated my post on top, but it still doesn't work. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, no. If it's a learning exercise, riddle it out. You will learn a lot else while doing so! If it will really, REALLY make a very significant difference to run one query instead of two, you should probably talk to an SQL expert (which I'm not) about coding it in raw SQL. My instinct is  to just use two queries.

Comment: Works now! Update the solution. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain function of itertools.

```
from itertools import chain

combined = chain(query1, query2)
```